# how to use a case statement in a sql where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a sql in the below format:

```
select distinct
      ora_hash( ah.target_name 
                   || to_char( start_timestamp, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' ))
         || ','
         || 'Critical'
         || ','
         || host_name
         || ','
         || ah.target_name
         || ','
         || 'Instance unexpectedly shutdown at '
         || to_char( start_timestamp, 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' )
   from 
      sysman_ro.mgmt$availability_history ah
         join sysman_ro.mgmt$target_members tm 
            on ah.target_name = tm.member_target_name
         join sysman_ro.mgmt$target mt 
            on ah.target_name = mt.target_name
            left outer join sysman_ro.mgmt$blackout_history bh  
               on mt.target_name = bh.target_name
   where 
          tm.aggregate_target_name like 'PROD_DB'
      and ah.availability_status_code = 0
      and ah.start_timestamp > sysdate -0.2
      and ah.start_timestamp > bh.start_time
      and ah.target_type = 'oracle_database'
```

Now the issue is that bh.start_time does not return anything for few targets.
So here i wanted to introduce a case statement such that if bh.start_time has a value(like 08-NOV-22) then the condition 'ah.start_timestamp > bh.start_time' should be taken into account and if there is no value returned for bh.start_time then the condition 'ah.start_timestamp > bh.start_time' should be skipped.

is this possible in the 'where'condition.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `case` *expression* (expression is something that evaluates to a value) to evaluate conditions based on other conditions. Use `AND/OR`: `case when <condition 1> then <condition 2> else <condition 3> end` is equivalent to `(<condition 1> and <condition 2>) or <condition 3>` (in SQL dialects with `boolean` data type)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a `CASE` statement, it's just an `OR` condition.  For example:

```
AND (bh.start_time IS NULL OR ah.start_timestamp > bh.start_time)
```

So the overall condition is satisfied if `start_time` is `NULL` *or* if `start_timestamp > start_time`.

Comment: Hi,but the bh.start-time is not even NULL...it is just blank

Comment: @svk: By "blank" do you mean an empty string?  Something else?  Whatever value you're looking for in the condition, just look for that value in the condition.  *In general* `NULL` is used to indicate that there is no value.  But if you need to compare your data with a specific value then compare it with that value.  For example: `bh.start_time IS NULL` checks if the column's value is `NULL`, or `bh.start_time = ''` checks if the column's value is an empty string, etc.

Comment: @svk In Oracle, an empty string and `NULL` are identical.

Comment: i mean ,when i run : select bh.start_time from  sysman_ro.mgmt$blackout_history bh
where bh.target_name like 'DB25%'   ..i get "no rows selected". So is ' ' the right choice?

Comment: @svk: All we can do is guess.  If you want to know what data is in your database then *you* would need to examine the data in your database.  For example, you can remove that part of the `WHERE` clause entirely, select all of the rows you want to examine, and in your debugger examine the exact value(s) of the data you're looking for.  Whatever value(s) you want to filter in your `WHERE` clause, that's what you'd use.  I really don't know any other way to explain it.  The *structure* you want is combinations of `AND` and `OR` to build your `WHERE` clause.  The *values* you use are up to you.

Answer (score 0):

First - CASE is an expression (not a statement). It works sequetialy and the first **WHEN** condition that is **True** will return **THEN** **value** and **EXIT** the **CASE**. That means you should order those when conditions in a way that it will give the result you want.
A small sample data (we don't know your data):

```sql
WITH
    ah AS
        (
            Select 1 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 13:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "AH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 16:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "AH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 19:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "AH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 22:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "AH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 23:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "AH_DATE" From Dual 
        ),
    bh AS
        (
            Select 1 "BH_ID", 1 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 07:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "BH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 2 "BH_ID", 1 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 09:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "BH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 3 "BH_ID", 3 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 19:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "BH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 4 "BH_ID", 3 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 20:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "BH_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 5 "BH_ID", 5 "AH_ID", To_Date('08.11.2022 21:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "BH_DATE" From Dual 
        )
```

If we left join the tables and if it was like
SYSDATE = To_Date('09.11.2022 01:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
I put in selection SYSDATE_LIMIT column just to be able to visualy compare the values that will be filtered later:

```sql
Select
    ah.AH_ID, 
    To_Char(ah.AH_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "AH_DATE",
  To_Char(To_Date('09.11.2022 01:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - 0.2, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "SYSDATE_LIMIT",
    bh.BH_ID, 
    To_Char(bh.BH_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') "BH_DATE"
From
    ah
Left Join
    bh ON(bh.AH_ID = ah.AH_ID)
```

Result is:

| AH_ID | AH_DATE | SYSDATE_LIMIT | BH_ID | BH_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08.11.2022 13:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 | 1 | 08.11.2022 07:00:00 |
| 1 | 08.11.2022 13:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 | 2 | 08.11.2022 09:00:00 |
| 2 | 08.11.2022 16:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 |  |  |
| 3 | 08.11.2022 19:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 | 3 | 08.11.2022 19:00:00 |
| 3 | 08.11.2022 19:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 | 4 | 08.11.2022 20:00:00 |
| 4 | 08.11.2022 22:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 |  |  |
| 5 | 08.11.2022 23:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 | 5 | 08.11.2022 21:00:00 |

One of the ways to do the filtering in WHERE clause using CASE expression could be like here (comments in code)

```sql
... ... ...
Where
    CASE 
        WHEN bh.BH_ID Is Null THEN 0            -- there is no matching row in bh table - excluded
        WHEN ah.AH_DATE <= bh.BH_DATE THEN 0        -- AH_DATE is not greater than BH_DATE - excluded
        WHEN ah.AH_DATE <= To_Date('09.11.2022 01:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') - 0.2 THEN 0  -- AH_DATE is not greater than SYSDATE - 0.2 - excluded
    ELSE 1      -- there is a row in bh table where AH_DATE is greater than BH_DATE and AH_DATE is greater than SYSDATE - 0.2   -  row returned
    END = 1
```

Result:

| AH_ID | AH_DATE | SYSDATE_LIMIT | BH_ID | BH_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 08.11.2022 23:00:00 | 08.11.2022 20:12:00 | 5 | 08.11.2022 21:00:00 |